# Subtract two strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I should calculate the difference between elements two different list. This is my code :

```
import operator
a   = ['5', '35.1', 'FFD']
b    = ['8.5', '11.3', 'AMM']      
difference = [each[0] - each[1] for each in zip(b, a)]
print difference
```

I need this output:

> b-a = ['3.5','-23.8','AMM-FFD']

I receive the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

**I don't want to use any class like `numpy` or `pandas`**

Comment: I am not sure how the difference between 5 and 8.5 should be 1.5...

Comment: Error is clear, so have you thought how to fix this?

Comment: That's why I'm trying to ask!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert numbers to `float`s, and if the elements cannot be converted to numbers, insert a `'-'` between them.

```
diffs = []
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    try:
        diffs.append(str(float(j) - float(i)))
    except ValueError:
        diffs.append('-'.join([j, i]))

>>> print(diffs)
['3.5', '-23.8', 'AMM-FFD']
```

Since python is **strongly** typed (not to be confused with **static** vs. **dynamic**) it does not implicitly perform arithmetic on the numeric interpretation of strings if it encounters an arithmetic operator between strings. There is no *obvious* behavior of the minus operator with regard to strings the way there is an obvious behavior of plus (i.e., concatenate).  Would you expect it to remove instances of the second string from the first string?  If so, there's already a more explicit `str.replace` method you can use.  Or would you expect it to remove the second string from the first only if the first string ends with the second string?  The expected behavior isn't 100% obvious, so the python authors did not include `__sub__` method support for strings.

Also, the `operator` module isn't used in your code, so no need to import it.